# Click image, replace it with two new clickable images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image (question mark image) inside a div like so

**HTML**

```
<div id="other">
    <img id="clickQues" class="quesMark" src="ques" />
</div>
```

I want this ques mark image to be replaced by two new clickable images (a tick, and a cross) when I click on it. I am using jQuery to achieve this. I am able to replace the images successfully. However, I am unable to click on the new tick, cross icons.

**My jQuery**

```
$('#clickQues').click(function(){
    $('.quesMark').hide();      
    $('#other').append("<img src='tick.png' id='tickIcon'>");
    $('#other').append("<img src='cross.png' id='crossIcon'>");
});

$('#tickIcon').click(function(){
    //hide the other cross icon
    //do something
});

$('#crossIcon').click(function(){
    //hide the other tick icon
    //do something
});
```

[Heres the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/misaal9/9zuG5/)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are added dynamically, you need to use event delegation

```
$('#other').on('click', '#tickIcon', function(){
    //hide the other cross icon
    //do something
});

$('#other').on('click', '#crossIcon', function(){
    //hide the other tick icon
    //do something
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fer7g/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('body').on('click','#tickIcon',function(){
    //hide the other cross icon
    //do something
});

$('body').on('click','#crossIcon',function(){
    //hide the other tick icon
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickQues').click(function () {
    $('.quesMark').hide();
    $('#other').append("<img id='tickIcon' src='http://www.pcdr.gr/moodle/theme/themza_moo_05/pix/i/tick_green_big.gif'>");
    $('#other').append("<img id='crossIcon' src='http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/VECTORNIGHT/general/jpg/16/cross_icon.jpg'>");
});

$('#other').on("click",'#tickIcon',function () {
    $('#crossIcon').hide();
});

$('#other').on("click",'#crossIcon',function () {
    //hide the other tick icon
    //do something
    $('#tickIcon').hide();
});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9zuG5/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickQues').click(function(){
    $('.quesMark').hide();      
    $('#other').append("<img class='right' src='tick.png' id='tickIcon'>");
    $('#other').append("<img class='close' src='cross.png' id='crossIcon'>");
});


$('.right').click(function () {
    $('.close').hide();
});

$('.close').click(function () {
    $('.right').hide();
});
```

Not tested but i think this will help you certainly  regards....:)